# Is there a portable way to extract part of formatted text?

Tags: linux, shell-script, osx

I have a program (specifically `node --version`) that outputs text in the form `v<major>.<minor>.<patch>`, where `<major>`, `<minor>` and `<patch>` are all numbers. I would like to extract the major version from this string in a portable way that works on both Linux and OS X. I am currently using

```
grep -oP "(?<=v)(\d+)(?=.\d+.\d+)"
```

but it looks like that does not work on OS X because it uses flags differently. Is there a way to do this that works on either system?

Comment: use `sed`: `sed 's/^v\([^.]\+\)\..*\..*/\1/'`

Comment: `sed` looks like a good way to do it. You should make that a full answer

Comment: you just want `node --version|cut -d. -f1`

Comment: @murgatroid99 Answer added..

Comment: @mikeserv That outputs the `v` too.

Comment: @murgatroid99 - you dont say what you do with it, but if you can strip that much with `cut` you can probably lose the `v`, too. I'm willing to bet `x=$(node --version | cut -d. -f1); printf %s\\n "${x#?}"` would work out for you.

Comment: @mikeserv I actually think that's better than the existing answer because it doesn't depend on a specific shell, so it's more portable. Can you make it an answer and explain a little more what it's doing? Specifically, I don't recognize the `x#?` syntax

Answer (score 2):

In bash, you can use:

```
IFS='v.' read -r throwaway major minor patch < <(node --version)
```

The variable `throwaway` gets the blank before the initial `v`. Don't have an OS X machine available to test, but that should be good bash script.

Comment: I can't tell what this is supposed to do. I don't get any output when I run it.

Comment: After running that, the numbers will be available in the shell variables `major`, `minor` and `patch`. Try `echo "major=$major minor=$minor patch=$patch"` after running it.

Comment: OK, I see now. This works for me on both machines I've tried it on (Ubuntu and OS X).

Comment: To do what I specifically wanted, I appended `&& echo $major` to that command.

Answer (score 0):

Inspired by mikeserv's comments, I am now doing this with the command

```
node --version | cut -d. -f1 | cut -c2-
```

This uses cut with the `.` delimiter to extract out just the `v<major>` string. Then it uses cut again to take all characters starting with the second, which removes the `v`.

This uses only coreutils (besides `node`), making it as portable as possible.